# I want to display 'yyy' in the index.html, but when running the server, the page displays normally but without the 'yyy'

Tags: python, html, django, view

i want to display `'yyy'` in the `index.html`, but when I run the server , the page is displayed normally but `'yyy'` is not visible.

#### view.py

```
def index(request):
   a1='yyy'
   return render(request, "index.html", a1)
```

#### index.html

[image]

I want to display `'yyy'` in the `index.html`. but when I run the server, the page displayed normally but `'yyy'` is not visible.

When I run:

python manage.py runserver

I see no errors.

Comment: index.html <h1>{{ a1 }} </h1> i want to display 'yyy' in the index.html.but when i run the server ,the page displayed normally but 'yyy' was not display .

Comment: You don't need to type the same message 5 times

Answer (score 1):

try this

you need pass dict into template from view.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context

```
def index(request):
   context = {'a1': 'yyy'}
   return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

in template

```
<h1>{{a1}}</h1>
```

Comment: thank you so much.  i am a fresh man here , i feel a little suprise  that i can receive a reply from the one who i don not know so quick.